# track and monitor package or exceuted file activity?

Tags: linux, monitoring, package, tracking

how to track all activity when run a executed file such as aptana studio or php storm?

## more explain

for example many software hide they user registred information to the special file, and when execute that software, first of all software read that file and check licence. i want to know where is that file?
i execute file from command line with `./excutedfile.sh`. and now how to track all activity for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try `strace` with filtering enabled like this?

```
$ strace -e trace=open -f gvim
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
(... snip ...)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY)     = 3      
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
Process 465 attached                             
[pid   464] open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
[pid   464] open("/usr/share/vim/vim74/lang/ja/LC_MESSAGES/vim.mo", O_RDONLY) = 5
[pid   464] open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 5
[pid   464] open("/lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color", O_RDONLY) = 5
[pid   464] open(".", O_RDONLY)         = 5      
[pid   464] open("/usr/share/vim/vimrc", O_RDONLY) = 5
[pid   464] open(".", O_RDONLY)         = 6      
[pid   464] open("/usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim", O_RDONLY) = 6
[pid   464] open("/etc/papersize", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = 7
[pid   464] open("/etc/papersize", O_RDONLY) = 7 
[pid   464] open(".", O_RDONLY)         = 6      
[pid   464] open("/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim", O_RDONLY) = 6
[pid   464] open(".", O_RDONLY)         = 7      
[pid   464] open("/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim", O_RDONLY) = 7
[pid   464] open(".", O_RDONLY)         = 8      
[pid   464] open("/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim", O_RDONLY) = 8
(... tons of output ...)
```

`-e trace=open` is to select only the `open(2)` syscall.  I added `-f` to trace child processes as well.

See also:

- http://chadfowler.com/blog/2014/01/26/the-magic-of-strace/
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html
- https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=strace